# DataTable selection of column from the Array of Fields

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

I have problem in selection of column from the array of fields into 
DataTable

```
Dim fieldList = ArrayOfFields
Dim DataToExport As DataTable = DataTableData
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Can you please be more specific about your problem? Read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Dim fil = fieldList.[Select](Function(l) l.Field).ToList()

Dim view As New System.Data.DataView(DataToExport)

Dim selected As System.Data.DataTable = view.ToTable("Selected", False, fil(0), fil(1))
instead of  fil(0),fil(1) i want to pass list fil

Comment: Could you edit your original post with the code from your comment? It's very hard to read in a comment.